Prove $(a^2+b)(b^2+c)(c^2+d)(d^2+a)\le64$ for nonnegative reals $a$ ,$b$, $c$, $d$ sum to $4$

Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ be nonnegative real numbers such that $a+b+c+d=4$. Prove that
$$\left(a^2+b\right)\left(b^2+c\right)\left(c^2+d\right)\left(d^2+a\right)\le64.$$

First, I tried mixing variables (for example setting $a$, $c$ both to $\frac{a+c}2$), but it didn't seem to work.
Then I thought of using the $2$ variable case, that is we have
$$x+y=2,~x,y\ge0\Rightarrow\left(x^2+y\right)\left(y^2+x\right)\le8.$$
This might be helpful because its equality case is $(x,y)=(2,0)$ or $(0,2)$, and that of the original problem is $(2,0,2,0)$ or $(0,2,0,2)$. From here, perhaps we could apply some kind of induction.

Where is this question from ?

I made it myself, and checked it by Mathematica. @EwanDelanoy

If I have to say, this problem is modified from https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1304222p6963023 but the two inequalities seem to be totally unrelated after the modification.

Proof. WLOG, assume that $d = \min(a, b, c, d)$. Let
$$P := (a^2+b)(b^2+c)(c^2+d)(d^2+a),$$
$$Q := (a^2+b)(b^2+a)(c^2+d)(d^2+c),$$
$$R := (a^2+d)(b^2+c)(c^2+b)(d^2+a).$$
We have
$$Q - P = (a^2+b)(c^2+d)\cdot (b+d)(b-d)(c-a),$$
$$R - P = (b^2+c)(d^2+a)\cdot (a+c)(b-d)(a-c).$$
Thus, $$P \le \max(Q, R).$$
To proceed, we need the following auxiliary result.
Fact 1. If $x, y, z, w\ge 0$ with $x + y + z + w = 4$, then
$(x^2+y)(y^2+x)(z^2+w)(w^2+z) \le 64$.
(The proof is given at the end.)
Now, we proceed. By Fact 1, we have $Q \le 64$ and $R \le 64$. Thus, $P \le 64$. We are done.

Proof of Fact 1.
WLOG, assume that $x + y \le z + w$. Then $z + w \ge 2$.
We have
$$(z + w)^3 - (z^2+w)(w^2+z)
= wz(3w + 3z - 1 - wz)$$
$$\ge wz (3w + 3z - 1 - (w+z)^2/4) \ge 0. \tag{A1}$$

If $x + y > 1$, we have
$$(x + y)^3 - (x^2+y)(y^2+x)
= xy(3x + 3y - 1 - xy) $$
$$\ge xy (3x + 3y - 1 - (x+y)^2/4) \ge 0.$$
Thus, we have $(x^2+y)(y^2+x)(z^2+w)(w^2+z)
\le (x+y)^3(z+w)^3 \le 64$ (by AM-GM).

If $x + y \le 1$, we have
$(x^2+y)(y^2+x) \le (x + y)(y + x) \le 1$.
From (A1), we have $(z^2+w)(w^2+z) \le 4^3$. Thus, we have $(x^2+y)(y^2+x)(z^2+w)(w^2+z) \le 64$.


We are done.

Thanks. Does the method generalize for $2n$ variables? By the way, the equality case is weird when there are $3$ variables (and probably whenever there are odd number of variables)

@youthdoo I think the method can not directly apply for $2n$ variables. 3 variable should be interesting.

@youthdoo The answer would greatly depend on the sum $S$ of the variables. If the sum is too small (even in this 4 variable case), then we drop into the $m< 3 - \sqrt{7}  \approx 0.354$ case. EG If the sum is $0.4$, then the max is $ (0.1^2 + 0.1)^4 > 0.2^6$. $\quad$ For a large enough sum like $ S = 2n $ (number of variables), then I can believe that the max is $ 8^n$.   And for $ S = 2n+1$, then the max is $ 2 \times 8^n$.

Yes, I meant the case where the sum of variables equals the amount of variables. But for $a+b+c=3$,$$\max\left{\prod_{\rm cyc}\left(a^2+b\right)\right}=\frac{121808+8309\sqrt[3]{28}-5936\sqrt[3]{98}}{9375}.$$I think the odd case is not nice to consider. @CalvinLin


Use the Reverse Rearrangement inequality to show that with $ \{ a, b, c, d \} = \{p, q, r, s \}$ and $ p \leq q \leq r \leq s$, we have

$$ ( a^2 +b)(b^2 + c)(c^2 +d)(d^2 + a) \leq (p^2 + s)(q^2 + r)( r^2 + q) ( s^2 + p)$$
That is the meat of my solution, so I'd enocurage you to focus on showing that. Once you have this idea, you can prove it by swapping variables till you get to the desired form. No surprise about the approach, since that is essentially the proof of reverse rearrangement.

Focus on the paired terms. We want to maximize $(p^2 + s) ( s^2 + p)$ subject to $p+s = m$.

Rewrite it as $f(m, x) = ((m-x)^2 + x ) ( x^2 + m-x) $, and taking derivatives yield $\frac{ df(m, x) } { dx } = 4x^3 -6mx^2 + (6m+2m^2)x -2x +m-3m^2$, with roots at $ x = \frac{m}{2}, \frac{1}{2} ( m \pm \sqrt{m^2 - 6m + 2 } ) $.
Note that $m^2 - 6m + 2 = 0$ at $ m = 3 \pm \sqrt{7}$.
So when $m < 3 - \sqrt{7}$ or $ m > 3 + \sqrt{7}$, then the maximum occurs at $ x = \frac{m}{2}$ with value $ (\frac{ m^2 + 2m } { 4} ) ^2$.
And when $ 3 - \sqrt{7} < m < 3+\sqrt{7}$, then the maximum occurs at $ x = 0, m$, with value $m^3$.

With $p+s = m, q+r = n, m+n = 4$, we seek the maximum of


$m^3 (4-m)^3$  if $ m > 3 - \sqrt{7}$.

It is well known that the maximum occurs at $m = 2$, with value 16.


$ (\frac{ m^2 + 2m } { 4} ) ^2 (4-m)^3 $ if $ m < 3 - \sqrt{7}$.

This can be bounded by $\frac{1}{16} (m+1)^4(4-m)^3$, which is maximized at $3 - \sqrt{7}$, and has a value that is $ < 11$.



Hence, the maximum occurs at $m= 2$.

Equality holds when $m=n = 2$, which means $\{ p, s \} = \{ q, r \} = \{ 2, 0 \}$. Converting back to the original conditions, we require $\{a, b\} = \{b, c \} = \{c, d \} = \{d, a \} = \{ 2, 0 \}$.
Hence, equality holds iff $ (0, 2, 0, 2)$ and $(2, 0, 2, 0)$.


I used the similar trick 1) to obtain a proof yesterday. I also found that 2) is not true when $m$ is sufficiently smalll; e.g. When $m = 1/4$, $p = s = 1/8$, we have $(p^2+s)(s^2+p) = 81/4096 > 1/64 = m^3 $. So I discuss two cases.

@RiverLi Oh dang it. The non-homogenous nature got in the way. Let me see if I can fix this.

@RiverLi K, I can stick a bandaid on it, but it's now very ugly :(

The Reverse Rearrangement Inequality is an interesting result. I have never seen it before.

@youthdoo It arose because there were several inequalities that essentially used this idea, esp when there are mixed variables. Always worthwhile to consider when you have an otherwise ugly product that you wish  would be much simpler (EG We changed this to a 2-variable inequality, then a 1-variable inequality.)

From the expression, it can be seen that $a$ and $c$ can be swapped and the result will be the same. Similarly, $b$ and $d$ can also be swapped. This is a bit easier to tell if we rearrange the expression to $(a^2+b)(c^2+d)\cdot(b^2+c)(d^2+a)$.
It's good to note that there are now two non-negative terms of a cyclic product in $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. To maximise the value of the expression, the values of both of these terms should be equal. This can be achieved by setting $a=c$ and $b=d$; the condition now becomes $a+b=2$, and the expression turns into
$$
\left(a^2+b\right)\left(b^2+a\right)\left(a^2+b\right)\left(b^2+a\right)
= \left(\left(a^2+b\right)\left(b^2+a\right)\right)^2.
$$
It thus suffices to prove that $\left(a^2+b\right)\left(b^2+a\right) \le 8$. This is a much easier task:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(a^2+b\right)\left(b^2+a\right)
&= a^2b^2+a^3+b^3+ab \\
&= (a+b)^3-3a^2b-3ab^2+a^2b^2+ab \\
&=8-ab(3a+3b-ab-1) \\
&=8-ab(5-ab)
\end{align}
$$
The R.H.S. is only greater than $8$ if $ab > 5$. But $ab=a(2-a)=2a-a^2$, which is never greater than $5$. So $(a^2+b)(b^2+a)\le8$ and we are done.

Consider the expression $E=-ac$, subject to the constraint $a\gt 0, c\gt 0, a+c=1$. Then $a$ and $c$ can be swapped in $E$. But $E$ is maximized, not when $a=c$, but when $a=0$ or $c=0$.

@EwanDelanoy Edited, I hope there is sufficient justification now.

No, it still isn't a justification. A very common misconception is to claim that "variables must be equal for equality to hold". EG Your reasoning claims that $AB$ is maximized when $A = B$. It also claims that $(2A) B$ is maximized when $ 2A = B$. At least one of those statements is false.

@CalvinLin I see your point, but in this specific case I'm also relying on $A$ and $B$ being terms of a cyclic product, which means it wouldn't apply if I tacked a $2$ onto $A$. Perhaps I could clarify that?

In general, you may NOT assume that "all variables must be equal", unless you check when does equality occur. $\quad$ You should clarify that, but it won't be sufficient. $\quad$ If you state ALL of your conditions explicitly, I can see if I can construct yet another counterexample to your claim (and will almost certainly be able to).

@CalvinLin yeah, I'm stumped. I'll see if I can find some reason or justification tomorrow, otherwise I don't really see a point in keeping this answer. Cheers.
